# Xamarin iOS - publish fails, started happening after iOS 13 update

Tags: ios, xamarin

had anyone see this issue, not able to publish to app store.
tried everything re-doing the icons, asset catalog, used mac machine, etc

any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You are missing an app icon in your assets take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue raised here is the reason for my builds failing
[issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6095)

installing this package breaks everything.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageCropper.Forms/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a required image on your iOS project. In order to verify this:

- Open your iOS project in Visual Studio,
- And most likely inside the Resources folder, you will see the Images.xcassets.
- When you open that, you will see "AppIcon" on the top.
- Open that and you will see several empty slots. If you hover over them, they will tell you what dimensions are needed.
- Drag and drop two pictures in the empty location that is required and it should fill up as shown in the picture below:

[image: Visual Studio XCode Assets]

- Most likely, you are missing the iPhone Spotlight 3x or iPhone App 2x image.

Comment: all files/icons are present on their right places, still upload to store fails. Also, this is not the first time publishing, a version of this app is already in the store. I am just doing the latest update.

Comment: Ah in that case you’d have to verify your info.plist file, the contents.json file and if neither work, unpack the IPA to see if the image is still attached. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71397/missing-required-file-icon-error-itms-90022-amp-itms-90023